# Show Saved Records in Read Only Mode on Refresh

Tags: apex, visualforce, dynamic-visualforce

I have a VF page in which I am saving and adding the values through two buttons. 
Buttons are working fine. when i click the add button, a new row is added and when i click on save button,data is saved in Read only mode. But when i refresh the page , the values are saved in edit mode and not in read only mode. So, my questions is how to Save the Data in Read only mode on Page refresh.

**Visualforce Page:**

```
<apex:page standardcontroller="Assigned_tasks__c" extensions="TestTaskController1">
<apex:form >
<apex:pageBlock > 
<div id="hide">
 <apex:pageBlockSection title="Input Page" id="pgsec" rendered="{!saved}">
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!reportlist}" var="acc"> 
<apex:column headerValue="Report Name"> 
<apex:inputField value="{!acc.Report_Name__c}" /> 

 <br /> </apex:column> 
  <apex:column headerValue="Comments">
 <apex:inputField value="{!acc.Comments__c}"/> 
 </apex:column> 
 <br/>
 </apex:pageBlockTable>
  </apex:pageBlockSection>
  </div>
 <apex:pageBlockSection title="Output Page"  rendered="{!saved1}">
 <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!reportlist}" var="acc"> 

 <apex:column headerValue="Report Name"> 
<apex:outputField value="{!acc.Report_Name__c}" />
 </apex:column> <br/>
  <apex:column headerValue="Comments">
<apex:outputField value="{!acc.Comments__c}" /> 
<br /> </apex:column> 

</apex:pageBlockTable>
 </apex:pageBlockSection>
 <apex:pageBlockButtons > 
<apex:commandButton value="Add Report" action="{!addAccount}"/>
 <apex:commandButton value="Save Report" action="{!saveAccount}"/> 
</apex:pageBlockButtons>
 </apex:pageBlock> 
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

**Apex Class:**

```
public class TestTaskController1 {

Report_Information__c task = new Report_Information__c();
Public boolean saved {get; set;}
Public boolean saved1 {get; set;}
public String parentId;

public list<Report_Information__c> reportlist{ get; set; }

    public TestTaskController1(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
              reportlist=new list<Report_Information__c>();
              parentId= controller.getId();
              reportlist = [SELECT id,Report_Name__c,Comments__c,ATask__c from Report_Information__c where ATask__c=:parentId];              
              reportlist.add(task);
              saved=true;
              saved1 = false;


    }


Public void addAccount()
{
Report_Information__c acc = new Report_Information__c();
reportlist.add(acc);
saved=true;
saved1=false;
}


public PageReference saveAccount() {
for(Report_Information__c  re :reportlist)
{

re.ATask__c= parentId;
}

if(reportlist.size()>1){
insert reportlist;
saved=false;
saved1= true;


}

return null;

}}
```

**Visualforce Screenshot:**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should have a wrapper class inside your controller that holds the custom object row and the flag:

```
public class TestTaskController1 {

   public class ReportInformation{
     public Report_Information__c task{get;set;}
     public Boolean saved{get;set;} 
   }

   public List<ReportInformation> reportInfos{get;set;}
 ...
}
```

Then on your page, you can display read-only vs editable view of the row like this:

```
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!reportInfos}" var="rInfo">
      <apex:column headerValue="Report Name">
         <apex:outputField value="{!rInfo.task.Report_Name__c}" rendered="{!rInfo.saved}"/>
         <apex:inputField value="{!rInfo.task.Report_Name__c}" rendered="{!NOT(rInfo.saved)}"/>
      </apex:column>
      <br/>
      <apex:column headerValue="Comments">
           <apex:outputField value="{!rInfo.task.Comments__c}" rendered="{!rInfo.saved}"/>
           <apex:inputField value="{!rInfo.task.Report_Name__c}" rendered="{!NOT(rInfo.saved)}"/>
           <br /> 
      </apex:column>
</apex:pageBlockTable>
```

UPDATE:

In the constructor, set them all to false, so the input fields are displayed. Then in your action method, set it to true. 
You should have a list of ReportInformation items like I have in my answer.
Iterate over your results from Report_Information__c and then add to the reportInfos list.

```
  for(Report_Information__C ri: [select id,... from Report_Information__C])
  {
   ReportInformation repInfo = new ReportInformation();
   repInfo.saved = false;
   repInfo.task = ri;
   repInfos.add(repInfo);
 }
```

HTH

Comment: 0
down vote
accept
Thanks for your reply, but how do i access my wrapper variables outside ? I created a variable from my wrapper class but how do I set my flag to true or false based on this variable ?

Comment: I am not able to understand, in my save action method or add action method I use it ??

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your reply, but how do i access my wrapper variables outside ? I created a variable from my wrapper class but how do I set my flag to true or false based on this variable ?

```
 public class TestTaskController2 {

 public class ReportInformation{
 Report_Information__c task = new Report_Information__c();

 Public boolean saved1 {get; set;}
 public String parentId;
  Public boolean saved {get; set;}
  }

 public ReportInformation rep {get;set;} ----> variable for my wrapper class
 public list<Report_Information__c> reportlist{ get; set;}
 public TestTaskController2(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {


          reportlist=new list<Report_Information__c>();
          rep.parentId= controller.getId();
          reportlist = [SELECT id,Report_Name__c,Comments__c,ATask__c from Report_Information__c where ATask__c=:rep.parentId];              
          reportlist.add(rep.task);
          saved = false; ----> how to set this flag using my wrapper class ?

}
```